# Safari: how to size the browser for the iPhone size (or some other solution)?

Tags: iphone, safari

I am coding a web app for an iPhone and I'm wondering how best to use Safari to develop for the iPhone, the main problem being that I've got is that Safari apparently cannot be resized to the narrow 320 pixels of width. How can I do that?

Any other tips and tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an environment to test, [Ripple emulator](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/) seems a nice option.

Comment: This looks great, I hope it delivers :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it quickly and simply by using a 320x480-sized `iframe`. Additionally, I added options to change the size (iPhone portrait, landscape, iPad, status bar or not, ...) and presto! an iPhone “simulator”!

Edit: that also allows the use of the Web Developer tools, they're invaluable in Safari or Chrome (I prefer to use the latter, but both are Webkit-powered).

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best way is to use a real device - iPhone or iPod touch - so you get a proper feel for how the device responds. If you're doing hefty animations, for example, testing on a desktop computer may leave you scrambling once you realize the entire page lags horribly on a real device the day before launch.

Barring that, you should use the iOS Simulator that comes with the xCode iOS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser extention or plug-in. For Safari there is ResponsiveResize for instance. You can donwload it [here](http://www.midwinter-dg.com/permalink-responsive-resize-a-safari-extension-to-help-with-responsive-design_2012-04-19.html). It allows you to use a predefined browser size, or use any custom size you'd like.

[image]